# PHP Code stopping short of breakpoint - HTTP 500 Error

Tags: php, html, apache

```
<?php

//Create Connection
$PokemonConnection=mysqli_connect("IP ADDRESS","USERNAME","PASSWORD","pokemon_test");

//Check Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$XenConnection=mysqli_connect("IP ADDRESS","USERNAME","PASSWORD","voyagers_xenFinal");

//Check Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Generating the PokeKey
$length = 14;
$PokeKey = "NG1PrB5myQZeWL";
//substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
echo $PokeKey;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $PokeKey;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $PokeKey;
echo 'Test 1';
//Getting Last Thread ID
$LastThreadQuery = "SELECT thread_id FROM xf_thread ORDER BY thread_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$LastThread = mysqli_query($XenConnection, $LastThreadQuery);
$LastThreadNum = mysql_numrows($LastThread);
echo $LastThreadNum;
echo 'Test 4';
mysqli_free_result($LastThread);
echo $LastThread;
echo 'Test 2';
//Generate Check Queries To Verify Existence and Eliminate Duplication Possibilities
$PokeKeyDuplicateCheck = mysqli_query($PokemonConnection, "SELECT POKEKEY FROM poketoken WHERE (POKEKEY = '".$PokeKey."') ORDER by POKEKEY DESC LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($PokemonConnection));
echo $PokeKeyDuplicateCheck['POKEKEY'];
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Test 3';
$ThreadExistCheck = mysqli_query($XenConnection,"SELECT thread_id FROM xf_thread WHERE (thread_id = '".$THREAD_ID."') ORDER by thread_id DESC LIMIT 1");
echo $ThreadExistCheck;
echo PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($PokemonConnection);
mysqli_close($XenConnection);
?>
```

Output:

```
NG1PrB5myQZeWL NG1PrB5myQZeWL NG1PrB5myQZeWLTest 1Test 4
```

Just moved from coding this project inside of Bash Unix Scripting to PHP and am gradually learning the language as I work through this Project.

Apologies for any neglection to syntax junkies!

Comment: The answer to your question is yes and, unless I'm mistaken, the code in your question proves it, and you've even already run the working code and gotten what I suspect is the expected output. Why did you even post this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it answers itself in the body of the question.

Comment: Because my code stops short of my test 4 breakpoint.

Comment: If the code does not execute all of my breakpoints there in lies an issue right?

Comment: In addition I ask this because I'm having issues getting the query to execute and display their results which is why my question of this matter exists.

Comment: @CodyGarrett Then please edit it; the question in the topic doesn't seem to match with what you want to ask.

Comment: Understood. The question name is edited. Apologies for the error on my behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 Error shows up if your script (or server, but in this case script) has an error and is configured to not show details to users. This is a good configuration for production environments as users won't be annoyed with unreadable details and hackers can't easily gather backend information, but it's bad for development purposes as you don't know where your errors are.

---

In your case, there's a simple script error:

```
$LastThreadNum = mysql_numrows($LastThread);
```

You use an outdated function of the mysql-extension for a mysqli result object, this probably throws the error.

---

EDIT: Spotted two more errors:

```
$ThreadExistCheck = mysqli_query($XenConnection,"SELECT thread_id FROM xf_thread WHERE (thread_id = '".$THREAD_ID."') ORDER by thread_id DESC LIMIT 1");
echo $ThreadExistCheck;

$PokeKeyDuplicateCheck = mysqli_query($PokemonConnection, "SELECT POKEKEY FROM poketoken WHERE (POKEKEY = '".$PokeKey."') ORDER by POKEKEY DESC LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($PokemonConnection));
echo $PokeKeyDuplicateCheck['POKEKEY'];
```

Both are pretty much the same error, you use a mysqli result object as a string/array;

```
$ThreadExistCheck = mysqli_query($XenConnection,"SELECT thread_id FROM xf_thread WHERE (thread_id = '".$THREAD_ID."') ORDER by thread_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$ThreadExistCheck = mysqli_fetch_row($ThreadExistCheck)[0];
echo $ThreadExistCheck;

$PokeKeyDuplicateCheck = mysqli_query($PokemonConnection, "SELECT POKEKEY FROM poketoken WHERE (POKEKEY = '".$PokeKey."') ORDER by POKEKEY DESC LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($PokemonConnection));
$PokeKeyDuplicateCheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PokeKeyDuplicateCheck);
echo $PokeKeyDuplicateCheck['POKEKEY'];
```

You need to use a function to get the actual data out of your result. [`mysqli_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_row) gives a numeric array with the data for each row, [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) an associative one (you can use ['row_name'] instead of numbers).